# R: How can I split one time period into multiple rows based on Dates

Tags: r, date, datetime

I am trying to splits time periods based on dates.
Each row in the dataset should be split into n periods

1. Start date to End of Year (31 Dec)
2. Beginning of year to Start Date
3. Start Date in new year to End of Year
   and so on ... till it reaches the End Date

Also the rows should be repeated n times (specifically the ID)

Dataset before split:

```
df <- tribble(
    ~ID,      ~Start,       ~End    
    , 01, "2016-05-14", "2018-09-14"
    , 02, "2013-07-21", "2014-05-19"
)
```

| ID | Start | END |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | "2016-05-14" | "2018-09-14" |
| 02 | "2013-07-21" | "2014-05-19" |

Dataset after split (for the 1st row):

```
df_out <- tribble(
    ~ID, ~Period_Start  ~Period_End,  ~Days,
    , 01, "2016-05-14", "2016-12-31",  231,
    , 01, "2016-12-31", "2017-05-14",  164,
    , 01, "2017-05-14", "2017-12-31",  231,
    , 01, "2017-12-31", "2018-05-14",  133,
    , 01, "2018-05-14", "2018-09-14",  123,
)
```

| ID | Period_Start | Period_End | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2016-05-14 | 2016-12-31 | 231 |
| 01 | 2016-12-31 | 2017-05-14 | 164 |
| 01 | 2017-05-14 | 2017-12-31 | 231 |
| 01 | 2017-12-31 | 2018-05-14 | 133 |
| 01 | 2018-05-14 | 2018-09-14 | 123 |

Any help would be greatly appreciated!